# Why Python and node.js sort differently two arrays, but unitary elements work in the same way in the two languages?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pandas

Hello I have a CSV sorted by python script with pandas, and I'm checking in node.js but sorted method doesn't work the same way:

The arrays are the following:

```
> a
[ 1, 1, '7-Zip', 'IgorPavlov' ]
> b
[ 1, 1, '7-Zip ZS', 'Igor Pavlov, Tino Reichardt' ]
```

and the responses in the python and node code for each element in the array are the same

**node.js**

```
> a[0] <= b[0]
true
> a[1] <= b[1]
true
> a[2] <= b[2]
true
> a[3] <= b[3]
false
```

**python**

```
>>> a[0] <= b[0]
True
>>> a[1] <= b[1]
True
>>> a[2] <= b[2]
True
>>> a[3] <= b[3]
False
```

But the results for array sort are different:

**node.js**

```
> [a,b].sort()
[
  [ 1, 1, '7-Zip ZS', 'Igor Pavlov, Tino Reichardt' ],
  [ 1, 1, '7-Zip', 'IgorPavlov' ]
]
```

**python**

```
sorted([a,b])
> [[1, 1, '7-Zip', 'IgorPavlov'], [1, 1, '7-Zip ZS', 'Igor Pavlov, Tino Reichardt']]
```

The question is why node.js or python have different behaviour and how can I solve this in order to get the same result in the two languages, pandas sort of the same way.

Thanks.

Comment: Because JavaScript doesn't compare arrays by comparing the items at each position like Python does.

Comment: How can I apply the same logic then?

Comment: `console.log([a,b].sort((a,b)=>compareList(a,b))`  write your custom `compareList()` function